# how to print the adjacency list from my vector

Tags: c++

i just practicing graphs...taking input of adjacency list...but cannot print it out...help please...

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 10000//maximum node
vector<int >edges[MAX];
vector<int>cost[MAX];
int main()
{
    int n,e,i;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&e);
    for(int i=1;i<=e;i++)
    {
        int x,y;
        scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
        edges[x].push_back(y);
        cost[x].push_back(1);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cout << what_you_want_to_print << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need 2 for loops:

```
for(int a=0; a<MAX; a++) {
  for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = edges.begin(); i != edges.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << endl;
}
```

and do same for cost. Note you will probably have empty lines, but you could modify your code to exclude empty vectors.